# How to delete a Stock Item attached file

Tags: acumatica

So i'm using the REST API for Acumatica and I'm trying to delete an attached file on a StockItem.

I have tried using the PUT method with the StockItem and in the files array setting the delete flag to true and then passing then entire entity to the put method. It comes back with a 200 but the file remains on the StockItem.

Any ideas?

Comment: As I know REST API doesn't support deletion of the files directly. You can create a custom page showing the list of the attachments and work with that page from the REST API.

Comment: okay cool. thank you.